# Почему сумма чисел взятых из строчных значений после SUBSTR округляется?

Tags: sql, oracle

Хочу перевести строчку `TAH_START (VARCHAR2)` из формата времени в часах:минутах в число  `TAH_START_NUM (NUMBER(19))`.

Например, `08:56` надо представить как `08 + 56/60 = 8.93333333`.

Я попробовал так:

```sql
UPDATE TEST_TABLE
SET TAH_START_NUM = substr(TAH_START, 1, 2) + (substr(TAH_START, 4, 2) / 60)
```

После выполнения данные выглядят так:

```
16:21   16
08:24   8
08:47   9
...
05:35   6
```

Но результат не выглядит как ожидалось, думаю, проблема в строчном формате чисел.

Comment: Уточните пожалуста,  `TAH_START_NUM` это кол-вo часов после полуночи, правильно?

Comment: Это количество часов, причем не дата, а суммарное количество (например, проведенного времени в чем-либо). Оно может быть больше 24, "40:23", например.

Comment: Ошибся, прошу прощения: Сверху комментарий про TAH_START. TAH_START_NUM - это конвертирование TAH_START по формуле часы + минуты/60. На самом деле, вопрос можно поставить проще, как сложить несколько чисел из строчки формата VARCHAR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обьявление типа колонки `NUMBER(19)` это укороченная форма записи `NUMBER(19,0)`.
Что произойдёт, если эти значения будут превышены? Коротко из [оф. документации](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-75209AF6-476D-4C44-A5DC-5FA70D701B78):

> `NUMBER(p,s)`
>   - *p* is the precision ...
>   - *s* is the scale ...
>   [...]
>   If a value exceeds the precision, then Oracle returns an error. If a **value exceeds the scale**, then Oracle **rounds it**.

Значение будет округленно. Решением будет, или отказаться от ограничения вообще, или указать для него разумные значения соглано тех. заданию. Например:

```sql
create table t1 (val varchar2 (5), num number (19)); 
insert into t1 (val)
    select trim (column_value) 
    from xmlTable ('"08:56", "16:21"');

update t1 
    set num = substr (val, 1, 2) + (substr (val, 4, 2) / 60); 

select * from t1;

VAL          NUM
----- ----------
08:56          9
16:21         16

rollback;
alter table t1 modify (num number (6,4));
```

Повторите вставку и обновление, и вывод результата теперь ожидаемый:

```
VAL          NUM
----- ----------
08:56 8,9333    
16:21 16,35
```

Comment: Как вы получили этот результат? Как обьявлены колонки в таблице?

Comment: TAH_START - VARCHAR2, данные забиты вручную.
TAH_START_NUM - NUMBER(19), данные забиты по SQL запросу, который я использовал в самом вопросе, вроде, такой же, как у Вас.

Comment: _вроде, такой же, как у Вас_ - они отличаются

Comment: UPDATE TEST_TABLE
SET TAH_START_NUM = 0 + substr (tah_start, 1, 2) + (substr (tah_start, 4, 2) / 60)

Получается, такой запрос должен быть? Он так же выводит округленное..

Comment: Ваша проблема - number (19) , это только целочисленные значения.

Comment: @Gipnomanul, замените `number(19)` -> `number(10,2)`

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы. Большое спасибо.

Comment: Рад был помочь! Я всё таки немного переработаю и вопрос, и ответ, чтобы источник ошибки был очевиден. Пока он только в комментариях.